# Change a Border Background inside a BasedOn ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

Here is the XAML in my application resources that globally changes all of the Button controls in the application to look and behave like I want:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0" 
                            Background="CornflowerBlue" BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- a bunch o' triggers here -->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

On one of my application's user controls, I would like to change some properties of this button. Here is some XAML that I am using in the UserControl.Resources section now to do this:

```
<Style x:Key="SpecialButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value=">" />
    <Setter Property="Border" Value="#eeeeee" />
    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#eeeeee" />
</Style>
```

The Button controls on my UserControl that I assign the style to of SpecialButton have the correct width, visibility, and content, but these last two attempts do not work. How would I go about changing the background color of the Border with a name of "Border" from the application resource in this SpecialButton style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use `TemplateBinding` to set the Background property on the control, in the base style.  Also in the base style, set the Background color to the default "CornflowerBlue".

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>    
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

Now you can overwrite the Background in the derived style:

```
<Style x:Key="SpecialButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#eeeeee" />
```

---

<sub>(Note that, if you want to use other properties that aren't defined on the Button control -- or, say you wanted to use multiple background colors -- then you'd have to create your own control that inherits `Button`, and expose the new properties as Dependency Properties.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was not exactly right but it led me down the right path. My original question had an `x:Key` on the Style element in the first XAML snippet, and this was not in the XAML in my app. As a result, I had to use `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"` in my second XAML snippet to get it to respect the changes to the original style.